# Typing a custom react-redux connect function in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a large, complex application that I'm attempting to migrate to Typescript. One particular constraint we have is that we make use of createProvider and the storeKey option for connecting our containers to the store. Given that we have north of 100 containers I've created a helper function to automatically pass this option by default. It's pretty simple and has worked as predicted in regular JS.

```
function connectToStore(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps, options = {}) {
     const finalOpts = { ...options, storeKey: STORE_KEY };
     return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps || {}, mergeProps, finalOpts);
}
```

How do I type this function? I've looked at the nightmare that is the type declarations for connect and am wondering if there is anyway to avoid reproducing the ones that the original uses. Surely there has to be a more terse approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-redux `connect` has a lot of overloads, and some of the auxiliary type aliases are unions of multiple alternatives; I imagine you only need some of these cases (e.g., only the overloads with four parameters).  If I were in your situation, I would just make a copy of the `connect` typings and start commenting out the cases I believe don't apply to `connectToStore`.  Once all calls to `connectToStore` are successfully type-checked, you can delete the commented-out cases.

Comment: Though I didn't end up using this approach, I did suspect that this was the appropriate solution and am marking this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Connect } from "react-redux";

const connectToStore: Connect = (
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps,
  options = {}
) => {
  const finalOpts = { ...options, storeKey: STORE_KEY };
  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps || {},
    mergeProps,
    finalOpts
  );
};
```